# Creating Array with String and Integers from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Currently I've got the following JSON feed:

```
var data = {
  "feeds": {
    "regions": [{
        "name": "Lichtenberg",
        "id": "01408.b",
        "suburbs": [{
            "name": "Fennpfuhl",
            "views": 76400
          },
          {
            "name": "Lichtenberg",
            "views": 87895
          },
          {
            "name": "Rummelsberg",
            "views": 10239
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Mitte",
        "id": "03442.f",
        "suburbs": [{
            "name": "Tiergarten",
            "views": 82695
          },
          {
            "name": "Mitte",
            "views": 67234
          },
          {
            "name": "Hansaviertel",
            "views": 10848
          },
          {
            "name": "Moabit",
            "views": 67500
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg",
        "id": "01991.o",
        "suburbs": [{
            "name": "Friedrichshain",
            "views": "98494"
          },
          {
            "name": "Kreuzberg",
            "views": "27800"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Templehof-Schöneberg",
        "id": "01778.k",
        "suburbs": [{
            "name": "Friedenau",
            "views": 76595
          },
          {
            "name": "Schöneberg",
            "views": 20731
          },
          {
            "name": "Templehof",
            "views": 58000
          },
          {
            "name": "Mariendorf",
            "views": 32300
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Pankow",
        "id": "02761.q",
        "suburbs": [{
            "name": "Wießensee",
            "views": 81294
          },
          {
            "name": "Prenzlauer Berg",
            "views": 76470
          },
          {
            "name": "Pankow",
            "views": 90210
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
};
```

Effectively I want to do two things:

1. Loop through the Regions to get the 4 names
2. Loop through all the views in each region, sum them up, and return them as values under the 4 names.

Here's a sample of the output that I just quickly typed up:

```
var viewsPerRegion = 

 [{
  label: "Litchtenberg",
  total: 174534
}, {
  label: "Mitte",
  total: 228277
}, {
  label: "Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg",
  total:  126294
}, {
  label: "Templehof-Schöneberg",
  total: 187626
}]; 
etc...
```

I do want to note that data.feeds.region[2].suburbs.views is stored as a string, so that's something I'll need to change into an integer first.

Anyway the solution I have so far (which doesn't really work) is as follows:

```
var viewsPerRegion, i, j, x;  

for (i in data.feeds.regions) {
  x += data.feeds.regions[i].name;
  for (j in data.feeds.regions[i].suburbs.views){
    x += data.feeds.regions[i].suburbs.views[j];
  }
}

viewsPerRegion = x;
```

Any help is certainly appreciated - bit of a newbie in JSON and javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `map` the regions array, extracting the `name` from each, and get the `total` by using `reduce` to add up each of the `views`:

```js
const data={"feeds":{"regions":[{"name":"Lichtenberg","id":"01408.b","suburbs":[{"name":"Fennpfuhl","views":76400},{"name":"Lichtenberg","views":87895},{"name":"Rummelsberg","views":10239}]},{"name":"Mitte","id":"03442.f","suburbs":[{"name":"Tiergarten","views":82695},{"name":"Mitte","views":67234},{"name":"Hansaviertel","views":10848},{"name":"Moabit","views":67500}]},{"name":"Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg","id":"01991.o","suburbs":[{"name":"Friedrichshain","views":"98494"},{"name":"Kreuzberg","views":"27800"}]},{"name":"Templehof-Schöneberg","id":"01778.k","suburbs":[{"name":"Friedenau","views":76595},{"name":"Schöneberg","views":20731},{"name":"Templehof","views":58000},{"name":"Mariendorf","views":32300}]},{"name":"Pankow","id":"02761.q","suburbs":[{"name":"Wießensee","views":81294},{"name":"Prenzlauer Berg","views":76470},{"name":"Pankow","views":90210}]}],}}

const viewsPerRegion = data.feeds.regions.map(({ name, suburbs }) => ({
  label: name,
  total: suburbs.reduce((a, { views }) => a + Number(views), 0)
}));
console.log(viewsPerRegion);
```

Comment: Thank you! This certainly works!! I saw that you use `map` and `reduce` instead of a `for-in` loop. Was my approach completely wrong in this case?

Comment: Array methods are more functional and generally have fewer problems than `for` loops. For example, your `for (i` created a *global* `i`, as did your `for (j` - whereas if you used array methods, everything would be encapsulated as a parameter (and you wouldn't have to repeat the `data.feeds.regions[i]` code string multiple times). You also didn't declare `x` before using it, which will result in some odd string that looks something like `'undefined7640087895` etc.